# graphicspath requirements for auto-pst-pdf

Tags: graphics, compiling, eps, auto-pst-pdf

I am working on a document split into multiple files, and am using the package chemstyle to automatically number the compounds in my schemes. The package uses auto-pst-pdf to edit EPS files. It is working perfectly, as long as I only select one chapter to include in the compile.

e.g.

```
\mainmatter % book mode only
%\include{Introduction/introduction}
%\include{Experimental/experimental}
%\include{Chapter3/chapter3}
\include{Chapter4/chapter4}
%\include{Chapter5/chapter5}
%\include{Conclusions/conclusions}
```

However if I include 2 chapters (that have schemes in them), only the first chapter will show the EPS image correctly formatted with compounds numbered. The following chapter won't show the images at all.

I'm guessing that I am not specifying paths correctly for auto-pst-pdf to find them.

So my path for Chapter3 and Chapter4 looks like this, and appear at the top of each document respectively:

```
\ifpdf
    \graphicspath{{Chapter3/Chapter3Figs/PNG/}{Chapter3/Chapter3Figs/PDF/}{Chapter3/Chapter3Figs/}}
\else
    \graphicspath{{Chapter3/Chapter3Figs/EPS/}{Chapter3/Chapter3Figs/}}
\fi
```

and

```
\ifpdf
    \graphicspath{{Chapter4/Chapter4Figs/PNG/}{Chapter4/Chapter4Figs/PDF/}{Chapter4/Chapter4Figs/}}
\else
    \graphicspath{{Chapter4/Chapter4Figs/EPS/}{Chapter4/Chapter4Figs/}}
\fi
```

I keep the EPS files to be converted in the ChapterX/ChapterXFigs/EPS folder for each chapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no need to use a different path setting. Use

```
\graphicspath{{Chapter3/Chapter3Figs/PNG/}{Chapter3/Chapter3Figs/PDF/}%
 {Chapter3/Chapter3Figs/}{Chapter3/Chapter3Figs/EPS/}{Chapter3/Chapter3Figs/}}
```

then LaTeX should use the correct image extension itself.

Comment: Yes... I did end up doing this, and it worked. I used a LaTeX template, and it was set up to use \ifpdf.

Answer (score 0):

Finally worked it out...

I changed the

```
\ifpdf
    \graphicspath{{Chapter4/Chapter4Figs/PNG/}{Chapter4/Chapter4Figs/PDF/}{Chapter4/Chapter4Figs/}}
\else
    \graphicspath{{Chapter4/Chapter4Figs/EPS/}{Chapter4/Chapter4Figs/}}
\fi
```

to just

```
\graphicspath{{Chapter4/Chapter4Figs/PDF/}{Chapter4/Chapter4Figs/EPS/}}
```

for each separate tex file included in the main.tex, and that solved the problem.

Not sure why the original statement worked at all when I included only one external .tex file, but all good now.